# Is it possible to connect to a System DSN on remote machine?

Tags: windows, odbc

We have a DSN on machine A that points to a DB on machine B. We have a machine C, that we want to be able to use that DSN on machine A...but we don't want to create the DSN on machine C.

Is there a way to use the System DSN on machine A from machine C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A system DSN, by definition, is local to the computer it's configured on.  You'll need to create it on the other server.

An alternative option is to use a DSN-less connect string, if possible.

Comment: Unfortunate.  We're trying to avoid creating a DSN on that computer, and the connection string option is failing and we can't figure out why.  (and the driver/db vendor is no help so far.)  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: (Assuming I don't get an answer that contradicts this, or provides a great deal more detail, relatively soon, I'll mark this as accepted.)

Answer (score 2):

No, the purpose of a DSN is a connection from one machine to one data source. It is not possible to the best of my knowledge to "proxy" a DSN connection from one machine to the other.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can... i know this answer don't bother you after several years of asking this question, but i think it might help other people looking out for it.

You can achieve this using DSN less approach

**For Example :** connection string for SQL server DSN

```
oConn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};" & _
           "Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;" & _
           "Address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,1433;" & _
           "Network=DBMSSOCN;" & _
           "Database=myDatabaseName;" & _
           "Uid=myUsername;" & _
           "Pwd=myPassword"
```

I have already tried it myself, however you need to have sufficient access rights

More DSN connection strings can be found [Here](http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=90)

Comment: is it possible to use a TOAD application on machine C such that machine A becomes a tunnel? If yes, how can one investigate this scenario if this action was performed maliciously?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but it requires a third-party solution such as [that from my employer](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-odbc-mt/).

These solutions typically entail installing some components on the data consuming machine (C) and some components on the machine with the ODBC DSN (A).  The connection winds up looking like

```
ODBC consumer on C
   -> ODBC Bridge DSN on C
       -> ODBC Bridge components on A
           -> ODBC DSN on A
               -> target DBMS on B
```